# Getting null values in action with List parameter

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

Im passing array data from angularjs to mvc controller

```
 This is my angularjs code
$http({
        url: '/Login/InsertDetails',
        method: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(Data),
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
    })
```

Json Data is

```
    $scope.details = [{
    name: "ammin",
    age: "16",
    city: "NY",
    add: "true",
    sal: 100
}, {
    name: "joe",
    age: "80",
    city: "CH",
    add: false,
    sal: 200
}];
   var Data = {
        one: $scope.details

    }
```

And in my controller i have method Insert with list parameter

```
public JsonResult Insert(List<Personel> P)
{

}
```

View Model class is like this

```
   public class Personel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string add { get; set; }
    public string sal { get; set; }
}
```

But im getting null values in action method when i post the data from angularjs. what type of parameter should i use in action method

Comment: can you add json data that you post

Comment: i added Json data

Comment: I am not familiar with angular but as I predict you wrap your data with another class and in the controller you try to get List. if you wrap your List in a Class and the list  property that  object will be filled.